# Sed cannot convert uppercase to lowercase

Tags: bash, sed

I want to change the "email address" variance in a jSON message to lowercase. I tried to use sed but failed, since the \L option does not work for me. Did I miss something?

```
a="{"id":null,"enabled":true,"password":"","email":"Foo@bar.com","lastName":"Foo","firstName":"lol"}"
echo $a | sed -e 's/email:[[:graph:]].*,last/\L&/g'
```

The result shows:

```
{id:null,enabled:true,password:,{L}email:Foo@bar.com,lastName:Foo,firstName:lol}
```

The result I want:

```
{id:null,enabled:true,password:,email:foo@bar.com,lastName:Foo,firstName:lol}
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  You might want to specify which OS and which version of `sed` that you are using.

Comment: Are you using GNU sed? Your code works in GNU sed version 4.2.1.

To find out which version you are using,

    sed --version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume that you do not have GNU sed and therefore do not have access to `\L`.  Instead, try perl:

```
echo "$a" | perl -pe 's/(email:[[:graph:]]*,last)/\L\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/email/) $i=tolower($i)}1' <<< "$a"
{id:null enabled:true password: email:foo@bar.com lastName:Foo firstName:lol}
```

Comment: @lifeGoGoGo `awk` is a very powerful too to manipulate files. I do suggest you try it out.